# Missing 'manifest.php' file in 'SuiteCRM-Outlook-Plugin v 1.1.0.9' plugin

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

When I install `SuiteCRM-Outlook-Plugin v 1.1.0.9` plugin in `SuiteCRM` it's generate error like missing `manifest.php`.

In short plugin has no `manifest.php` file in his directory.

Could you provide me to the `manifest.php` file of `SuiteCRM-Outlook-Plugin v 1.1.0.9` plugin.

Here `SuiteCRM-Outlook-Plugin v 1.1.0.9` is a plugin of `SuiteCRM`

Comment: the question is not clear and way too generic. can you please, be more specific? here're some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also mention which version of suitecrm you are using?